# kubectl fails with "Unable to connect to the server: EOF" in docker container on mac but not on linux

Tags: docker, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, google-kubernetes-engine, macos-big-sur

Since a while back we have been using a docker container to do deployments to a GKE cluster. The container is based on one of googles cloud SDK images. The docker file looks something like:

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:322.0.0-alpine
RUN gcloud components install kubectl
...
# The docker image will also include any manifests etc. that is supposed to be deployed...
```

This image is then built and launched using docker exec running any number of `kubectlt` commands against the cluster configured.

The same approach is used in a VS Code development container using the same Google Cloud SDK image as base image.

This has been working quite well and the method has been used as part of a deployment workflow in Jenkins as well as locally on a Mac workstation.

For a couple of weeks now - it does not work locally on the Mac anymore.

So:

- Building and running the image on a AWS (Ubuntu) instance and deploying to GKE works.
- Building and running the the image on a Multipass (Ubuntu) instance on the Intel Mac works.
- Building and running the image on Docker Desktop for Mac (3.3.1) on the same Mac does **NOT** work. `kubectl` fails with a `Unable to connect to the server: EOF` message

(Running `kubectl` natively on the same Mac works though!)

It seems the underlying curl request sent by kubeclt is denied during the initial SSL handshake but this might not bre related.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can try change the version of docker desktop for mac and see if it works. However, it could be some sort of incompatibility with some MacOS version/libs version. There are 2 github issues that you can follow.
[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2747
[2] https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40512

Comment: Are you able to connect to the Kube API endpoint from within your container in Docker Desktop via curl directly?

Comment: No, i'm not, it's seems to bail on the initial TLS handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue connecting to GKE clusters from inside a Docker container for several months. After digging into it, all of my `curl` requests to the GKE cluster endpoints were throwing `OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`, which led me to this issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5524.

Downloading the latest Docker Desktop for Mac update fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, now it works for mer as well. Odd, sometimes simply waiting solved the problem:-)